# Replication successful but slave skips certain queries

Tags: mysql, replication

I am testing a MySQL master-slave replication. Here is the **master** `my.cnf`:

```
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
server-id=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
```

Here is **slave** `my.cnf`:

```
server-id=3
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
relay-log=/var/log/mysql/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index=/var/log/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
log-slave-updates=1
replicate-wild-do-table = ads.%
replicate-ignore-db = mysql
replicate-ignore-db = test
```

Everything works fine but if I execute something like this on master, it won't replicate to slave.

```
use test;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

If I omit `use test`, the replication is successful.

I would like to skip test db from replication but also need to avoid the above mentioned issue. I have searched a number of posts but couldn't find a solution. Am I missing anything simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--replicate-ignore-db applies only to the default database (determined by the USE statement). Because the `ads` database was specified explicitly in the statement, the statement has not been replicated.

My advice is to change the context with a `USE` instead of explicitly specify the database in the statement.

Max

**EDIT (for questions)**

**1.**

> Ok, got it but then what should be the my.cnf values if I want to log all databases on the master but selectively replicate on slave (like ignoring test and replicating ads)?

Note that your syntax is correct, all statements will be written on binary log (master) and the slave will ignore the `mysql` and `test` databases **BUT YOU SHOULD EXIT THE CONTEXT** `mysql` and `test` before run queries on other databases.

The context is `ads` : **REPLICATED**

```
USE ads;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

The context is `test`: **IGNORED**

```
USE test;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

The context is `toto`: **REPLICATED** because of your `replicate-wild-do-table` and toto is not ignored by a `replicate-ignore-db`

```
USE toto;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

**2.**

> Looks like "replicate-wild-do-table" means "replicate only this db and
>   ignore everything else".

`replicate-do-table=ads` will replicate statements on ads database (**your context should be ads**, `USE ads;`) and ignore the statements on other databases:

The context is `ads` : **REPLICATED**

```
USE ads;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

The context is `test` : **IGNORED**

```
USE test;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

`replicate-wild-do-table=ads` will replicate statements on ads database **even if your are in an other context** (`test` for instance), and ignore the statements on other databases.

The context is `ads` : **REPLICATED**

```
USE ads;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

The context is `test` : **REPLICATED**

```
USE test;
INSERT INTO ads.users ( id , username ) VALUES ( 19, 'tyy' );
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116404/discussion-on-answer-by-maxime-fouilleul-replication-successful-but-slave-skips).